# Mypy: incompatible type error during set update

Tags: python, types, mypy, typing

Mypy returns an error if the **set** is updated with new **tuple** using `add()`

**code.py**

```
adgroups_by_campaign_id: Dict[CampaignId, Set[str]] = defaultdict(set)
for customer_id, campaign_ids in campaigns_per_customer_id.items():
    adgroups = get_adgroups_in_campaings(ads_client, customer_id, campaign_ids, adgroup_names)
    for adgroup in adgroups:
        adgroups_by_campaign_id[CampaignId(adgroup['campaign_id'])].add(
            (adgroup['adgroup_name'], adgroup['adgroup_resource_name']) -> RETURN ERROR
        )
```

**error body**

```
 error: Argument 1 to "add" of "set" has incompatible type "Tuple[str, str]"; expected "str"
```

As far as I know, it is common practice to add new tuplets to the set.

> The add() method can add a tuple object as an element in the set

Why does mypy think it's not allowed?

Comment: Because you told mypy earlier that it's a `Set[str]`

Comment: The error message is clear, you annotated it as a `Set[str]`, but you are trying to add a `Tuple[str, str]` to this set, but it requires a `str`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adgroups_by_campaign_id` is marked as `Dict[CampaignId, Set[str]]` meaning that `mypy` will expect all the values to be sets that contain strings, not tuples of strings.

`Set[str]` should be changed to `Set[Tuple[str, str]]`.

Comment: My inattention. Thank you!